# primr 5 edition. unique_ptr constructor from custom deleter function

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

On C++ primer 5 edition. Chapter 12. Dynamic memory. The table that shows `std::unique_ptr` operations:

> `unique_ptr<T, D>` u2      Null `unique_ptr`s that can point to objects of type `T`. `u2` will use a callable object of type `D` in place of `delete` to free its pointer.
>
> `unique_ptr<T, D> u(d)`     Null `unique_ptr` that points to objects of type `T` that uses `d`, which must be an object of type `D` in place of `delete`.

But if I try to create one like this:

```
void cust_del(std::string* pStr){
     std::cout << *pStr + " destroying..." << std::endl;
     delete pStr;
}

int main(){


    {// new scope
    std::unique_ptr<std::string, void(*)(std::string*)> u(cust_del); // error

    std::unique_ptr<std::string, void(*)(std::string*)> u(new string("Hello unique!"), cust_del); // ok
    // or
    // std::unique_ptr<std::string, decltype(&cust_del)> u(new string("Hello unique!"), cust_del);

    }

}
```

So as I can see it is not possible to construct a `unique_ptr` just from the custom delete function.

- One last point: it is said there:

> Unlike shared_ptr, there is no library function comparable to make_shared that
>   returns a unique_ptr. Instead, when we define a unique_ptr, we bind it to a
>   pointer returned by new. As with shared_ptrs, we must use the direct form of
>   initialization:

But there is `std::make_unique`. Is this because `make_unique`is added by C++14 and the book has been rewritten for C++11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` doesn't have a constructor that only takes a custom deleter. You'd have to pass `nullptr` as the pointer value if you want a null pointer with a custom deleter.

On your second point, that is correct. They didn't add make_unique until c++14, for really no other reason than that C++11 was a huge revision and some features didn't make it in.